# Merge Rows to combine data in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
  Centre Name Open Click Train  Home  Online
0 5431   Ed   10   4     Nan    Y     Nan
1 5431   Ed   10   4     Y      Nan   Y
2 7267   Joe  7    3     Y      Y     Nan
3 8921   Alex 6    2     Nan    Nan   Y
4 8921   Alex 6    2     Y      Nan   Nan
5 4796   Roly 9    5     Nan    Nan   Nan
```

I want to merge the rows so I have one row per 'Centre' but retain the 'Y' from both duplicated rows. So my desired outcome will be:

Desired outcome:

```
  Centre Name Open Click Train  Home  Online
0 5431   Ed   10   4      Y     Y     Y
1 7267   Joe  7    3      Y     Y     Nan
2 8921   Alex 6    2      Y     Nan   Y   
3 4796   Roly 9    5      Nan   Nan   Nan
```

I want to retain Nan where it appears in the same column on duplicate rows as I will later replace Nan with 'N'

Comment: `df.replace('Nan', np.nan).groupby(['Centre', 'Name', 'Open', 'Click'], as_index=False).first()`